# Inet address 127.0.0.1:9042 is not available when use ccm start

Tags: cassandra, ccm

I use CCM to create a three node Cassandra cluster on a single machine.  When I use ccm start at a linux terminal, I see this error:

```
ccmlib.common.UnavailableSocketError: Inet address 127.0.0.1:9042 is not available: 
[Errno 98] Address already in use; a cluster may already be running or you may
need to add the loopback alias
```

Answer (score 2):

There could be several reasons:

- You have Cassandra process that is already running - check, with `ps -aux|grep -i cassandra` that you don't have other Cassandra processes running already on localhost
- You haven't created additional interfaces as described in the [CCM documentation](https://github.com/riptano/ccm) or [this article](https://academy.datastax.com/planet-cassandra/getting-started-with-ccm-cassandra-cluster-manager) - create necessary interfaces/aliases (this depend on your OS).